# How to find IMEI and IMSI id in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I can find **UDID** using this code

```
UIDevice *device=[UIDevice currentdevice];  
NSString *ss=[NSString stringWithFormate:"%@",[device currentdevice].uniqueidentifier;
```

But I don't know how to find **IMEI** and **IMSI** id programatically, any one have an idea please help to me.

Answer (score 6):

There's no public API for this.

It's possible using IOKit, but that's not a documented API on iOS, so you can't use it for App Store apps.